# Problem ordering sequelize query by date, in ascending order

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sequelize.js

I need to order a sequelize query by date ascending. What I'm trying to sort out is the result of the model: ExamScore (as student_score).

Note that in the ordering I am setting the column "updated_at" and the way of ordering. However, it is not working, it simply does not order.

```
const students = await Students.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'name', 'cpf'],
    include: [
      {
        model: Status,
        attributes: ['status', 'updated_at'],
        as: 'student_status',
        where: [{ course_id }],
        required: false,
      },
      {
        model: ExamScore,
        attributes: ['score', 'updated_at'],
        as: 'student_score',
        where: [{ module_id }],
        required: false,
        order: [['updated_at', 'ASC']],
      },
    ],
  });
```

Below is an example of the return from this query:

```
{
    "id": 30014,
    "name": "Jon Doe",
    "cpf": "xxxxxxxx",
    "student_status": [
        {
            "status": "APROVADO",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-27T03:06:14.502Z"
        }
    ],
    "student_score": [
        {
            "score": "9.00",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-27T03:06:13.998Z"
        },
        {
            "score": "2.00",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-27T02:59:22.571Z"
        }
    ]
},
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding order to your top query, not inside includes.

Example:

```
const students = await Students.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'name', 'cpf'],
    include: [
      {
        model: Status,
        attributes: ['status', 'updated_at'],
        as: 'student_status',
        where: [{ course_id }],
        required: false,
      },
      {
        model: ExamScore,
        attributes: ['score', 'updated_at'],
        as: 'student_score',
        where: [{ module_id }],
        required: false,
      },
    ],
    // add the order, model ExamScore with alias student_score
    order: [[{ model: ExamScore, as: 'student_score' }, 'updated_at', 'ASC']],
  });
```

Comment: Could I use where in the same way?

Comment: @Fred you can do something like this: `where: {
  '$student_score.score$': 100
}`. This will check if the score is 100.